# Calling module controller function from child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My first try at angularjs.

I'm trying to create a directive that will, on click, call a function that is declared in the model's controller function.

Here is my simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/vnj62xn8/

JS:

```
angular.module('tasks', [])
.controller('taskCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.complete = function(){
        console.log('parent function');
    }
})
.directive('taskList', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            complete: '&'
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="complete()">Complete Task</button>',
        controller: function($scope){
            /*$scope.complete = function(){
                console.log('child function');
            }*/
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="tasks">
    <task-list></task-list>
</div>
```

I've looked at other Q/As on SO and found that this seems to be the most generalized solution, although it will never call the complete() function found in the taskCtrl controller. It will, however, call the complete() function from the directive's controller, if uncommented. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to set up funciton binding (for `complete: '&'`) as well. `<task-list complete="functionFromController()"></task-list>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the html as following:

```
<div ng-controller="taskCtrl">
    <task-list complete="complete()"></task-list>
</div>
```

Here is the link to updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paila/vnj62xn8/4/

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle, but it still won't hit the parent function: http://jsfiddle.net/vnj62xn8/2/

Comment: Updated the answer. You are missing the ng-controller="taskCtrl" div.

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help. If I can ask you another question, since I'm trying to implement this into my project - the following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vnj62xn8/5/ my directive/controller are part of a submodule, but I can't locate them anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Prusprus can you add a seperate question for this? As this question is answered this will lead to wrong discussion. I can definetly help you.

Comment: Found my problem, but will do if I have another question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your code to :

```
.directive('taskList', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            complete: '&'
        },
        template: '<button ng-click="complete()">Complete Task</button>',
        controller: 'taskCtrl' // Here you are referencing the taskCtrl
    }
});
```

You just need to reference your existing controller inside the controller assignment

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my example case. However, is it possible to have your directive define its controller, while extending the functions from the module's controller?